# Turn column data to columns and group by that

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
Month    Type
JAN        A
JAN        A
FEB        B
FEB        B
FEB        A
FEB        A
```

I want to run a query that groups by month and counts the occurrences of a type for that month.
So for the table above, the output should be:

```
        A     B
JAN     2     0
FEB     2     2
```

It's probably not possible, but thought I'd give it a shot.
Thank you.

Comment: Are A and B the only options? Is that fixed and hard-coded?

Comment: Ah, no, there's an unknown number of types sadly.

Comment: info here might help: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL does not have a `PIVOT` function which is basically what you are trying to do. So you will need to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT Month,
  SUM(case when type = 'A' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as A,
  SUM(case when type = 'B' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as B
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY month
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8181/1)

Now if you want to perform this dynamically, meaning you do not know ahead of time the columns to transpose, then you should review the following article:

[Dynamic pivot tables (transform rows to columns)](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)

Your code would look like this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'SUM(case when type = ''',
      type,
      ''' then 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ',
      type
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM test;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT month, ', @sql, ' FROM test GROUP BY month');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8181/7)

Comment: This is really mind blowing. I had no idea MySQL could do dynamic pivot tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a variable number of columns using only SQL itself. The best you can do with a query is to group by `Month`, then `Type` :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY Month, Type
```

This way you will end up with :

```
JAN   A   2
JAN   B   0
FEB   A   2
FEB   B   2
```

Which can be transformed into or treated as a pivot table (like your example) with minimal effort in any programming language.